# Photo upload CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, upload

When I upload a photo using CodeIgniter, the name of the image is changed to a random name like "107fb08f4a11cc37a040237cdcf0e48a.jpg" for example. I am having trouble showing the image from the database in the view because it is showing the original upload name and not the new name. How do I disable the function that changes this name?

These are the config settings:

```
$config = array(
    'upload_path'   => './uploads/',
    'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
    'max_size'  => '6000',
    'max_width' => '2068',
    'max_height'    => '1032',
    'encrypt_name'  => true,
);
```

Answer (score 4):

change :

```
'encrypt_name'  => true,
```

to:

```
'encrypt_name'  => false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
encrypt_name = "false"
```

Also remember that if this option is set to false then by default the codeigniter framework make the duplicate copies of the filename that are uploaded to the server by adding the integer value in front of the filename.
In case you dont want duplicated files on the server, please set the overwrite option to true.

```
overwrite = true
```